# How to send a key combination in VIM terminal insert mode?

Tags: vim, qemu

I use vim inline terminal to run a QEMU program and create a key mapping to do it:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F9> :terminal  ./run-qemu.sh<CR>
```

I also want to create a key mapping to exit the opened terminal window. Two things should be done:

1. In terminal insert mode, map <F10> to <C-A>x, which is the exit key combination of QEMU.
2. After doing step (1), vim should change to terminal normal mode(because the given process is exit), then just create a mapping to `:q<CR>`.

The problem I'm having is, in step (1), I can't create a key mapping to simulate key presses.

I have tied the following code but not work.

```
tnoremap <F10> <C-a>x
```

Is there something wrong? Or is there any other way to complete my task(e.g. work with bash script)?

Comment: Did you try to map it to `quit<CR>` instead of the key combination?

Comment: @Tekki Thanks for your reply. I finally found that the problem is about **the chosen of target key**. In the above, I chose `<F10>` as target key, which may be special and not work. After I use another target key(not function key), everything is OK. But I don't know why.